# Sort a 2d array by the first column and then by the second one

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```java
int[][] arrs = {{1, 100}, {11, 22}, {1, 11}, {2, 12}};
Arrays.sort(arrs, (a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0]));
```

Above array has been sorted as

```
{1, 100}
{1, 11}
{2, 12}
{11, 22}
```

I want them to be sorted by `a[0]-b[0]` first and if `a[0]=b[0]`, then sort them by `a[1]-b[1]`.

```
{1, 11}
{1, 100}
{2, 12}
{11, 22}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is to compare the inner arrays [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) (like how words are ordered in a dictionary). [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) does exactly that.

```
Arrays.sort(arrs, Arrays::compare);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a chain of comparators as follows:

```java
int[][] arrs = {{1, 100}, {11, 22}, {1, 11}, {2, 12}};

Arrays.sort(arrs, Comparator
        .<int[]>comparingInt(arr -> arr[0]).thenComparing(arr -> arr[1]));

Arrays.stream(arrs).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[1, 11]
[1, 100]
[2, 12]
[11, 22]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Sorting a 2d array in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65733452/14940971)</sup>